# Horizontal ListView.builder with Items of dynamic height

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-listview

I am trying to make a `ListView.builder` with items of different and dynamic height. I am trying to make a scrollable listview of workout schedule widgets.

I did most of the code, right now i am able to create the schedules and show them in the ListView.builder. The problem is that each item is currently taking the fixed height and not its minimal height. As you can see in the following [attachments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw6SX.jpg).

This is the code in my Scaffold.

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                height: 850, // This is a temporary height, since i would like it to be dynamic.
                child: ListView.builder(
                
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: _ritornaSchedaDiAllenamento(size)[2], // The element at [2] is an int and it tells ListView.builder how many Items it must show
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return _ritornaSchedaDiAllenamento(size)[0][index]; // This generate the widgets.
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Now, this is the function that returns the widgets that Listview.builder shows.

```
            // This is the function that returns the Widgets that the Listview.builder shows.
            
            List _ritornaSchedaDiAllenamento(Size size) {
                    List<String> nomiDelleSchede = []; // This list contains the NAME of each workout schedule
                    List<Widget> schede = []; // This list contains workout schedules WIDGETS and SEPARATORS (basically SizedBox with given width)
                    int numerowidget = 0; // This int is the number of items Listview.builder has to create, it will update later.
            
                Color _coloreScheda(int indice) {
                  // This function assign a color to each workout schedule, based on the index (indice) of the Workout Schedule.
            
                  Color colore = Colors.white;
            
            
                  if (indice == 0) {
                    colore = Color(0xFF1a88ff);
                  } else if (indice == 1) {
                    colore = Color(0xFF29ccae);
                  } else if (indice == 2) {
                    colore = Color(0xffED254E);
                  }
            
                  if (indice > 2) {
                    if (indice % 3 == 0) {
                      colore = Color(0xFF1a88ff);
                    }
                    if (indice % 3 == 1) {
                      colore = Color(0xFF29ccae);
                    }
                    if (indice % 3 == 2) {
                      colore = Colors.black;
                    }
                  }
            
                  return colore;
                }
        
        // Now, i create the single workout schedule (scheda), at first it is only a container with
        // Text widget saying "No schedule found". 
        
                Widget scheda = Container(
                  child: Text("No schedule found"),
                );
        
        // So, how i generate the Workout Schedules Widgets? I look at the whole list of exercise 
        // (listaesercizi), if an exercise has the field .allenamentoNome, which is a String and 
        // also the Workout schedule name, with a name that is not present in "nomiDelleSchede" 
        // which contains every workout schedules names, then i add the name of that Schedule 
        // (.allenamentoNome) to the list of all schedules name (nomiDelleSchede).
            
                for (int i = 0; i < listaesercizi.length; i++) {
                  if (!nomiDelleSchede.contains(listaesercizi[i].allenamentoNome)) {
                    nomiDelleSchede.add(listaesercizi[i].allenamentoNome);
                  }
                }
            // Now, if nomiDelleSchede is not Empty, (basically if the user has created an exercise and it has assigned that exercise to a workout schedule named "Leg day", with the field .allenamentoNome), i create the single workout schedule widget (scheda).
    
    // Please note how "schede" is the list of widgets that containts each workout schedule widget (scheda) and separators. Meanwhile, "scheda" it's the single colored workout schedule widget. 
    
                if (nomiDelleSchede.isNotEmpty) {
                  schede.add(
                    SizedBox(
                      width: size.width * 0.10,
                    ),
                  );
                  for (int i = 0; i < nomiDelleSchede.length; i++) {
                    scheda = Container(
                      width: size.width * 0.80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: _coloreScheda(
                            i), // I assign the color based on the index 'i'
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29.5),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                            child: Text(
                              nomiDelleSchede[i],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 40),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 60,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 9,
                                        child: Container(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          //  color: Colors.red,
                                          child: const FittedBox(
                                            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Esercizio',
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const Expanded(
                                        flex: 2,
                                        child: FittedBox(
                                          fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "S",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 2,
                                        child: Container(
                                          //  color: Colors.red,
                                          child: const FittedBox(
                                            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                            child: Text(
                                              "R",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 2,
                                        child: Container(
                                          //  color: Colors.red,
                                          child: const FittedBox(
                                            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.check_circle,
                                              //Icons.check_rounded,
                                              size: 22,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
            
                                            // child: Text(
                                            //   "F",
                                            //   style: TextStyle(
                                            //     color: Colors.white,
                                            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            //   ),
                                            // ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          AllenamentoLista(
                            listaesercizi: listaesercizi,
                            nomeScheda: nomiDelleSchede[i],
                            coloreprincipale: _coloreScheda(i),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );

// Now i add the widget of the workout schedule to "schede" which contains every widget ListView.builder has to show (Each Workout Schedule Widget (scheda) and Separator (SizedBox)

                    schede.add(scheda);
            
                    // Adding 20 pixel of space between each workout schedule
                    if (i != nomiDelleSchede.length - 1) {
                      schede.add(
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
            
                  // After the last workout schedule i add some space in order to center the last // workout schedule
                  schede.add(
                    SizedBox(
                      width: size.width * 0.10,
                    ),
                  );
                }
            
                if (nomiDelleSchede.length != 0) {
                  numerowidget = schede.length;
                }
            
                return [schede, nomiDelleSchede, numerowidget];
              }

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw6SX.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it! This simple way works!

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: _ritornaSchedaDiAllenamento(size)[0],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```